# Getting/setting a function as a property on a class (TypeScript)

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to create a class which looks like this:

```
class Foo {
  _bar?: () => void; // this is a property which will invoke a function, if it is defined

  set bar(barFunctionDef: () => void) { // this stores a reference to the function which we'll want to invoke
    this._bar = barFunctionDef;
  }

  get bar() { // this should either invoke the function, or return a reference to the function so that it can be invoked
    return this._bar;
  }

  doSomething() { // this is what will be called in an external class
    if(condition) {
      this.bar; // this is where I would like to invoke the function (bar)
    }
  }
}
```

Essentially, I want to have a class which will store references to functions which will be optionally set. There will be many "bar" class properties which will all have the type `() => void`.

Is there a "correct" way to call `this.bar` inside `doSomething` in order to invoke the function that is stored on that property?

Comment: `this.bar()` to invoke it? If that doesn't work, then I don't understand the question.

Comment: When I call `this.bar()` I get this error:
`Uncaught TypeError: this.bar is not a function`

I tried to debug, and I found that when I console log `this.bar` it's undefined. I think my set function might be incorrect.

Comment: Then you need to share the code you have that is wrong as a [mcve]. Asking a conceptual question where the answer is "Yes, that works" for a concrete case where it *doesn't* work isn't likely to help you.

Comment: It should work if you set `bar` correctly with a function. [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ncvldt)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if that's what you're trying to achieve, but I set up an example of generic implementation [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-gfkszt)

```
type MethodReturnsVoid = () => void;

class Foo {
  methods: Map<string, MethodReturnsVoid>;

  constructor() {
    this.methods = new Map();
  }

  public getMethod(methodName: string): MethodReturnsVoid {
    if (this.methods.has(methodName)) {
      return this.methods.get(methodName);
    }

    return null;
  }

  public setMethod(methodName: string, method: () => void): void {
    this.methods.set(methodName, method);
  }
}

const foo = new Foo();
const func: MethodReturnsVoid = () => console.log('func');
const anotherFunc: MethodReturnsVoid = () => console.log('anotherFunc');

foo.setMethod('func', func);
foo.setMethod('anotherFunc', anotherFunc);

const methodFunc = foo.getMethod('func');
if (methodFunc) methodFunc();

const methodAnotherFunc = foo.getMethod('anotherFunc');
if (methodAnotherFunc) methodAnotherFunc();
```

Comment: `foo.getMethod('func')()` will throw errors if `foo.getMethod('func')` returns undefined. You should definitely check whether or not the function exists first. OP's code is fine, he just didnt add enough information to reproduce the error he's getting.

Comment: Thanks @MikeS. fixed per your comment